# Convert alphanumeric string to integer in Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that contains a multi-column primary key. For the purpose of ETL job, I need to concatenate all primary key columns into a single column for de-duplication.

Let's say that my combined primary key are:

jesse_20230431_low
james_20230431_high

Is there anyway for me to convert that into a number that retains its uniqueness? Figure every character can be represented by a number no? Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ascii() value of each character but the string will be huge.

Query:

```
with cte as
  (
    SELECT ascii( unnest( string_to_array('jesse_20230431_low james_20230431_high', NULL) ) ) col 
  )
select string_agg(cast(col as varchar),'') from cte
```

Output:

| string_agg |
| --- |
| 10610111511510195504850514852514995108111119321069710910111595504850514852514995104105103104 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JjC_TTDB)